# How to mention a user in a message with discord.js?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am implementing a command to mute users. For example, the following command would mute the user `@anon` for 5 seconds:

```
!mute @anon 5
```

My program listens for the `message` event, mutes the user and sends a confirmation message like this:

```
@anon#1234 has now been muted for 5 s
```

Unfortunately Discord does not recognize the username in this message as a mention. How can I mention a specific user with the `msg.channel.send` function? This sample includes the code which sends the confirmation message:

```js
bot.on("message", msg => {
    let args = msg.content.substring(PREFIX.length).split(" ")
    let time = args[2]
    let person = msg.guild.member(msg.mentions.users.first() || msg.guild.members.fetch(args[1]))

    // muting the user here and sending confirmation message
    msg.channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has now been muted for ${time} s`)

    setTimeout(() => {
        // unmuting the user after specified time and 
        // sending confirmation message
        msg.channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has been unmuted.`)
    }, time * 1000);
})
```

The muting is not included in this sample, it works. The messages are being sent correctly but the user is not mentioned, meaning the username is not clickable and doesn't get highlighted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The documentation recommends [this way](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User?scrollTo=toString) to mention a user:

```js
const message = `${user} has been muted`;
```

The example above uses template strings, therefore the [`toString`](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.14.1/User:Class#toString) method of the [`User`](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.14.1/User:Class) object is called automatically. It can be called manually though:

```js
const message = user.toString() + "has been muted";
```

The documentation states:

> When concatenated with a string, this [the user object] automatically returns the user's mention instead of the User object.

Which means that every time `toString` is invoked, either by templates, string concatenation or by manually calling `toString`, the user object will be converted to a mention. Discord will interpret the output correctly, highlights it and makes it clickable.

---

In your case you would use the above example like this:

```js
msg.channel.send(`${person.user} has now been muted for ${time} s`)
setTimeout(() => {
    ...
    msg.channel.send(`${person.user} has been unmuted.`)
}, time * 1000)
```

Answer (score 14):

You can also tag users by

```js
`<@${id}>` // users
`<@&${id}>` // roles
```

Of course you'd need to know the user id or role id to do that.

Comment: This is unnecessary extra work. `role.toString()` and `user.toString()` and `member.toString()` all handle this for you. Or if you use them in a template literal, you can be even lazier and just use `${role}`, `${user}`, or `${member}`, etc. This also works for channels.

Comment: This was helpful thank you. In my case I don't have the user object on hand when it comes time to create a message to reply to a user's command. So in my case re-constructing the user object by fetching a user from the client is unnecessary extra work.

Answer (score 0):

Also, as of 2024, you can import `userMention()` from **discord.js** and pass in a user object:

```
userMention(user)
```